# cannot disable scroll lock in libreoffice-calc (using a dell xps)

Tags: dell, libreoffice

I have a dell xps which has no scroll-lock key.

Nevertheless, when I open libreoffice-calc the scrolllock mode is enabled and I can't disable it, which renders calc completely useless.

Is there some way to disable it or to emulate pressing the scroll-lock key?

Using ubuntu 18.04.5, libreoffice-calc: 6.0.7.3

Comment: You might wish to view this resource: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/92025/how-to-disable-scroll-lock-feature-in-calc/

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Switch Keyboard Layouts

After trying many things the most untechical solution, just switching keyboard layouts to another language and back (DE->EN->DE for me) has surprisingly worked.

#### 2. Try to disable scroll lock manually

##### Via the accessibility feature

Try to enable the keyboard screen-overlay in the accessebility settings, on some versions there might be a scroll lock key, sometimes there are just the letters.

##### On xfce Desktops

```bash
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

remove: `grp_led:scroll` from `XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"`

##### On gnome desktops

remove: `'grp_led:scroll'` from

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
```

by executing

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'numpad:microsoft']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I could solve it uninstalling calc and removing the config folder, like this:

```
sudo apt purge libreoffice-*

rm -fr ~/.config/libreoffice/

sudo apt install libreoffice-calc
```

I guess there must be a better solution, but I'll leave it here until a better answer pops up

Comment: Didn't work for me.